# I have created a container div as follows using html in drupal but its not responsive

Tags: html, drupal

I have created a container div as follows using html in `drupal` but its not responsive.

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <img alt="" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="49d2d4ef-b208-4284-80e0-872a0e5185fc" src="/sites/default/files/2021-09/BMZ.svg" style="width:224px;height:148;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <img alt="" data-entity-type="file" data-entity-uuid="268a30b8-a17f-40ad-a837-4a4adcf03f4d" src="/sites/default/files/2021-09/UNCTAD_Official.svg" style="width:117px; height:148px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-align-center" style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-size: 13px; line-height: 21px; font-weight: 400; font-family: Raleway;">
       <i>The project is financed by the DeveloPPP program of the German Federal Ministry of Economic Cooperation and Development (BMZ).</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Click to view a screenshot of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxOPc.jpg)

Comment: Add more details. Which div is not responsive? What have u tried? What is your desired result?

Comment: Also, put your code within a pair of three backticks to be visible (``` ```)